# Play ogg with Cordova on Android and iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, ogg

I'm currently building a mobile app for Android - iOS with Cordova. The goal of this small app, is to stream an OGG song in live (why OGG?, because it's open-source and free from royalties).

My problem : OGG isn't read on devices with Android or iOS. I've already tested to decode OGG with javascript lib like ogv.js or aurora.js, but no conclusive results. Or the app is too greedy for the cpu or it does not work at all. 
Have you some others ideas to play OGG, i'm lost?

Comment: I'm lost too, but I'm looking for mp3 decoder without lagging using `aurora.js` and `mp3.js`